# Is there a non-javascript/PHP way to write sample code that won't get evaluated?

Tags: html, css, pre

The `<pre>` and `<code>` tags are used for showing snippets of code and use a basic monospaced font and preserve all spacing, tabs, and line breaks. They still evaluate the code snippet, however, so that `<div>` has to be written as`&lt;div&gt;`, etc. Is there a simple and clean way to be able to present code snippets as they are written *without* needing to escape all the special characters? I tried searching for this question and couldn't find one, so forgive me if I still managed to somehow duplicate this question from elsewhere.

I want to just set up some kind of tag block that lets me copy and paste whole blocks of code *as-is* without needing to escape out all the `<'s` and `>'s`, etc.

Comment: There are hacks, like `<script type="text/plain">`, but those aren't really recommended. The real solution is to not put your sample in an HTML document.

Comment: If you're using a halfway decent text editor, it should be able to HTML-escape special characters in a selected block of text on the click of a button. You can't change HTML syntax. What if your sample HTML code contains a `</pre>`? There's no way for the browser to "know what you mean", you simply must escape it.

Comment: Wait a minute, of course there's an answer. Use XHTML! Then you have CDATA sections at your disposal. Sorry it took me 8 hours to think of that.